# How do I call a struct in a method so I can output it afterwards?

Tags: c#, data-structures, methods

I want to get x and y integers to output z, which is the product/sum of the two integers.
However, to do that I must somehow introduce the z variable (found in the struct) into the Update() method, and parameters don't seem to work since I would have to introduce them in both the struct and Main() method. It would create an infinite loop of introducing parameters.
I thought of trying to make an instance within the Update() method, but I can't seem to get it and somewhat confuse myself in the process.
For reference, here's my code:

```
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter: ");
            string oper1 = Console.ReadLine().PadRight(2);
            string oper2 = Console.ReadLine().PadLeft(2);
            string oper3 = ("[+ , -, *, /] Enter an operator and press the Enter key.");
            string[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/" };

            vector3 v = new vector3(int.Parse(oper1), int.Parse(oper2), 0);

        
            Update(v, oper3, operators);
        }

        public static void Update(vector3 v, string oper3, string[] operators)
        {
        

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine($"Enter operator: {operators}");
            string output = Console.ReadLine();

            //vector3 output2 = ();
        

            //bool containString = Z.Contains(operators);
      
            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hello");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nEnter the operator as shown and press the Enter key.");
          
                Update(v, oper3, operators);
            }
      
            Console.WriteLine($"[myInt1: {v.myInt1}, myInt2: {v.myInt2}, Z: {v.Z}]");
        }

        public struct vector3
        {
            public int myInt1;
            public int myInt2;
            public int Z;

            public vector3(int x, int y, int z)
            {
                myInt1 = x;
                myInt2 = y;
                Z = z;

              string output = Z.ToString();

          
            }

        }
    }
```

I was expecting to make an instance in the Update(), but it is not wanting to work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: fwiw, there's already a Vector3 struct included in .Net

Comment: System.Numerics.Vector3 has float fields so it's not interchangeable with this integer vector

Comment: Is this for a class assignment? Has polymorphism been introduced yet?

Comment: Remember a struct is passed by value not by reference. So The first value passed in will be the value coming out, it will not change.  Even though it is changed in the recursively called update functions. Update would need to return the vector to make this work.

Comment: _"and somewhat confuse myself in the process"_ - yeah, all of that sounds pretty confused. Non of the question text makes any sense to me. What do you mean by "call a struct", "introduce ..." and why would have "introducing" something have the effects you are describing?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve exactly?

> I want to get x and y integers to output z, which is the product/sum of the two integers.

If z is your result of calculation you did with operator input and myInt1, myInt2; then why there is no calculation? You just assign values to myInt1, myInt2, z.

> However, to do that I must somehow introduce the z variable (found in the struct) into the Update() method, and parameters don't seem to work since I would have to introduce them in both the struct and Main() method.

Another point is, since z is inside of vector struct, if you give vector as parameter to Update() method, then Update method have access to variables inside vector as well. You should keep in mind Stuart Smith's comment.

> I was expecting to make an instance in the Update(), but it is not wanting to work and I can't figure out why.

You should not make an vector instance if you have already vector parameter for this problem. But it does not mean you cannot. You probably miss some rules. Maybe you can ask the errors for this.

You can check how does parameters work again. Good luck.